# Can't find any documentation on how to change the moodle app appearance

Tags: css, moodle

I've managed to link my css sheet to the page and I know it's working because I can the colour of all the paragraph elements to purple and that's working but I've been looking all over to change the top banner colour but I can't find the name of the element anywhere. I even tried

```
*{
    background-color: #55499f;
}
```

and that hasn't changed the background colour of the banner

All my custom css is

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #3c0096;
    background-color: #55499f
}
a {
    color: #3c0096;
    text-decoration: none
}
div {
    background-color: #55499f;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to apply the background color to everything with `*`

Comment: I know but I just wanted to know if it would make a difference and it didn't appear to.

Comment: In that case, you must have other css overwriting this style. Can you share more of your css or a live example?

Comment: Moodle uses default it's own default css unless the user specifies certain elements and their changes so my style sheet literally just consists of body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #3c0096;
    background-color: #55499f
}
a {
    color: #3c0096;
    text-decoration: none
}
div {
    background-color: #55499f;
}

* {
    background-color: #55499f;
}

Comment: Can you do me a favor then and include your css and html in the question? Technically, you're supposed to do that for all questions here.

Comment: The CSS file defining the setting you want to change is probably in the theme you are currently using. Go into your_moodle_system/theme/your_chosen_theme/style/styles.css and try to change your setting there.

Comment: Chances are you: 1) Are adding the custom CSS to the wrong theme, 2) Need to purge caches.